# Check if the selected date is today's date or a future date in vuejs validations

Tags: vue.js, validation

In my vue js component I have a form with user having to select a start date from a date picker.

User should be able to pick a date which will be today's date or a future date.

```
<div class="w-1/2 mr-2">
                        <p class="text-certstyle-titles font-bold text-sm mb-1">Start date</p>
                        <div class="h-12">
                            <cs-date-picker
                                id="startDate"
                                v-model="project.start_date"
                                :default-selection="true"
                                :name="`${identifier}-start_at`">
                            </cs-date-picker>
                            <validator
                                :identifier="`${identifier}-validate-project`"
                                :rules="validations.startDate"
                                :name="`${identifier}-start_at`"
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I have following validation rule so far,

```
startDate: {
                    required: {
                        message: 'Project Start date is required.'
                    },
                },
```

How can I validate if the selected date is today's date or a future date?

Comment: Perhaps like this - `isPastDate(val) => { const today = new Date(); return today.getFullYear() + '-' + String(today.getMonth()+1).padStart(2,'0') + '-' + String(today.getDate()).padStart(2,'0') <= val || 'Dates in the past are now allowed'}`

Answer (score -1):

Why not use [vuetify's date picker](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/date-pickers/#readonly)?

```
 <v-date-picker
   v-model="dateTermino"
   :min="new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10)"
 ></v-date-picker>
```

By just settings the props min!